# Adding validation to auto complete .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui

I am trying to add validation check on this auto complete, however for some reason because its in an `each()` block it's causing me so many problems.

Full code:

```
<input type="text" class="productOptionSerialNumber" value="@opt.SerialNumber" data-part-num="@opt.PartNumber" />
```

```js
$(".productOptionSerialNumber").each(function () {
    var partNum = $(this).attr("data-part-num");
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "@Url.Action("SerialPartNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val() + "&partnum=" + partNum + "&callnum=" + $("#Form_Call_Num").val(),
        minlength: 2,
        delay: 300,
    })
});
```

For this .productOptionSerialNumber function i cannot do a validation.

i have a working example which has worked before (look below) but with this particular function it doesn't validate, i have tried to add it the same way i did before, but no luck.

Working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('input[name="Form.InstallType"]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();
    if (val == '1') {
        var validOptions = "@Url.Action("SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val();
        previousValue = "";

        $('#abc').autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: validOptions,
        }).change(function(){
            var source = validOptions;
            var found = $('.ui-autocomplete li').text().search(source);
            console.debug('found:' + found);
            var val = $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();

            if (found < 0 && val === '1') {
                $(this).val('');
                alert("You must select a value from the auto complete list!");
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

So if I don't choose from auto complete I get an alert. I am trying to implement this to the first part of code but because its in a `.each` and `.attr` it's not liking it this way.

Any ideas

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless you're using this plugin.  Edited.   Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky well its about validating my jquery, so you tell me can i use this instead. edited back to normal.

Comment: As per the [tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info), the [tag:jquery-validate] tag is for [**The jQuery Validate plugin** written and maintained by Jörn Zaefferer](http://jqueryvalidation.org).  Simply using jQuery for any form validation is not what this tag means.

Comment: "which does not like the way i have done it with this" Could you give a more precise description of the problem: is there an error shown in the console? Adding a code snippet or jsfiddle would help, also.

Comment: firstly, your autocomplete source should either be an array, or a url.. that when called.. will fetch an array.. you're using `@Url.Action`.. (so you're using Razor, right?... ensure you're parsing the page (handing the server-side functionality) and destinquish the difference between string parameters you're passing to your server-side razor helper method and the resulting client-side string (url) it will become (single quote, double quote)..

Comment: secondly, when/where/how is the each function being used?.. for the functioning one, I can say it is being executed in an anonymous function that is called with the DOM is ready.. at that point, the controls are going to be on the page.. I can't say the same for your each function...

Comment: thirdly, please review [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).. it doesn't seem like you would have an issue with the `this` instance, but you can be more explicit by defining the item and index parameters on the callback function and working with them.

Comment: lastly, since you're using data attributes, I recommend using jqueries method that facilitates them.. `$(selector).data("part-num")`.. but note that jquery will automatically parse the contents/value of the data attributes to json.. so ... your attribute declaration should look more like this.. `<input type="text" data-opt='{"partNumber": "@opt.PartNumber", "serialNumber" : "@opt.SerialNumber" }' ... />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional information I don't know what kind of problems you are experiencing with the each() loop, however what you are trying to accomplish is certainly do-able.

Here is an example, hopefully it will help you fill in anything you are missing on your end.

HTML

```
<label>productOption aaa:</label>
<input type="text" class="productOptionSerialNumber" value="" data-part-num="aaa" />
<br />
<br />
<label>productOption bbb:</label>
<input type="text" class="productOptionSerialNumber" value="" data-part-num="bbb" />
<br />
<br />
<label>productOption ccc:</label>
<input type="text" class="productOptionSerialNumber" value="" data-part-num="ccc" />
```

Jquery

```
var dataFromURL = {
    'aaa':['What','Is','Up'],
    'bbb':['Nothing','Much','Bro man'],
    'ccc':['Clown','Question','Bro schmoe']
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".productOptionSerialNumber").each(function () {
        var partNum = $(this).attr("data-part-num");
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: dataFromURL[partNum],
            minlength: 2,
            delay: 300,
        }).change(function(){
            var data = $(this).autocomplete( "option" ).source; 
            var found = data.indexOf($(this).val());

            if (found < 0) {
                alert("You must select a value from the auto complete list!");
                $(this).val('');
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkfs540q/)

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't specifically a reason it needs to only execute after autocomplete (i.e. validation can occur whenever there is a change -- which, from my understanding is what occurs in the old, working code), you can still bind your validation to $(this).

Also,is there a reason you removed .change() from the new code?

If the reason is because you can't apply the validation to everything in the each statement, you need to check for a unique selector before binding the validation (typically an  ID, but I see that there isn't one).

This code code does what I described. It uses ID as a unique selector. If adding an ID to the input tag is not an option, you'll need to find a different one.

```
$(".productOptionSerialNumber").each(function () {

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "@Url.Action("SerialPartNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val() + "&partnum=" + partNum + "&callnum=" + $("#Form_Call_Num").val(),
        minlength: 2,
        delay: 300,
    });

    if ($(this).attr('id') == "thisid")
        {
            $(this).bind('input propertychange',function(){ 
                alert('this code executed because the input box changed');
            });
        }
});
```